# How can I intentionally create a non-aligned numpy array?

Tags: numpy

I need to intentionally create a non-aligned numpy array. In particular, I want `PyArray_ISALIGNED(array)` to return false. What causes numpy arrays not to be aligned, and how can I easily, manually trigger those conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the details, there is a test in scipy.linalg that checks that misaligned arrays don't cause an error with Lapack.

http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/browser/trunk/scipy/linalg/tests/test_decomp.py?rev=#L1065

However, if you search scipy tickets, you see that there are some problems across various platforms.